# How can the rear camera flash be forced to on in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am attempting to force the flash to be on for an imagePicker but when I run the following code, it defaults to off.  Does anything else need to be done to force the flash on in Swift 3?

```
  let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
  imagePicker.delegate = self
  imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
  imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
  imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.on
  imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.rear;
  self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

A previous question was asked here for an older version of Swift:
[Camera Flash Turn Auto/On/Off with UIImagePickerController in IOS - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067202/camera-flash-turn-auto-on-off-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-ios-swift)

But, there appears to be some subtleties that I am missing to get it to work in Swift 3.

Comment: image must be take by UIImagePickerController ? if not did you try to use AVCapturePhotoOutput ? 
As sample : http://qiita.com/tfutada/items/3e415cbe176d6f801b1d
(written in japanese

Comment: Would prefer UIImagePickerController as it provides all that I need and is simple to operate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the camera flash mode in a completion closure as follows:

```
  self.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
  {
      imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.on
  }
```

The full source is as follows:

```
  let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
  imagePicker.delegate = self
  imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
  imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
  imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.rear;

  self.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
  {
      imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.on
  }
```

Verified that this works with Swift 3, but not sure if it helps for older versions.